# Flask - jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'index' is undefined

Tags: python, flask

it's a just simple task of a flask that picks jpg format file from user & saves to the particular folder but it gives me
this error:

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'index' is undefined

this is my Flask Code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
app_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
@app.route("/")
def index():
    target = os.path.join(app_root, 'txt/')
    print(target)
    if not os.path.isdir(target):
    os.mkdir(target)

for file in request.files.getlist("mp3_file"):
    print(file)
    file_name = file.filename
    destination = '/'.join([target, file_name])
    print(destination)
    file.save(destination)

return render_template('index.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

& this is my HTML Code(this code could have Bugs but right now flask showing error):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename = 
    'bootstrap.css') }}" /><!-- ../static/bootstrap.css -->
    </head>
    <body background="Bg.jpg">
    <center>
     <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url_for(index) }}">
        <table class="table table-hover" style="width:100px; background-color:rgba(102,102,102,0.9); border-radius:10px; margin:100px">
            <tr>
               <td class="text-right"><label class="text-white" style="margin-top:4%">Upload Your Audio file here: </label></td> 
               <td><input name="mp3_file" type="file" value="" class="text-white btn" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Submit" class="btn btn-dark" style="margin-left:45%" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">{% if file %}<textarea name="answer" rows="10" cols="100" content="{{ file }}" ></textarea>{% else %} <textarea name="answer" rows="10" cols="100" ></textarea> {% endif %}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `action="{{ url_for(index) }}"` Where is `index` defined?

Comment: u mean like this {{ url_for(index.html) }}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is in **action="{{ url_for(index) }}"**. You are using **index** as a variable but you are not passing anything to the template. I suppose you want to get the url of index, then wrap **index** with single quotes and it will work fine i.e:  action="{{ url_for(**'index'**) }}".

Comment: You should move your background image to static folder and change the link from "Bg.jpg" to "/static/Bg.jpg". For more knowledge about static files in flask check [here](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/static.html).